# Listener to input color box HTML JS

Tags: javascript, input, addeventlistener, event-listener, color-picker

Its is possible to add a listener to the html input color box ?
if yes how i can proceed ?
i try

```
  dataIntepretor.oninput =function(event){
```

and also

```
dataIntepretor.onchange =function(event){
```

what am checking for , is a live tinit color apply to my sprite.
Those listener only work when i click ok, but i need a listener thats can detect the current live color selected, without click on ok.

example here :

[image]

So i would like to add a listener to this input color box
thanks

Comment: ??? i don't use library and i have a color picker, am on a node app with chromium and html5

Comment: <input type="color" value="#ffffff" id="v-tint" propName="tint">
                </div>

Comment: Sorry, my bad. With this one, you can't, but another color picker will do. eg: http://jscolor.com/

Comment: nice , i will maybe use, but i want know if existe a native way to do this with listener

Comment: It has the same listener as type="text", so no...